# Google Map v2: how to retrieve existing google markers from google Gmap2 object

Tags: google-maps

I hope the title is clear. I would like to retrieve the existing google markers from my Gmap2 object. Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a property on the [GMap2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2) object to access [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker) objects that you have previously added using [addOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.addOverlay).  If you want access to them later, you will need to store a reference to those objects.